# SQLPLUS result set - output to file AND insert into table

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, sqlplus, spool

I need to output the results of select query via SQLPLUS into a file and then also insert those records into a "sent" table. Though what I can't figure out is how to then re-use that result to store in the "sent" table. Would I have to use a cursor? I'm not very familiar with cursors but I was thinking that might be the solution? Is there another way? By the way this is in a shell script.

Here is what I have so far:

```
sqlplus -S <<ENDOFSQL  || eval 'echo "Error occurred during sqlplus command line $LINENO" 1>&2; exit 1'
$USER/$PW@//$IP_PORT/$DB
SET PAGESIZE 50000
set feedback off
SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
SET NUM 24
SPOOL REPORT.xls

select * from SOMETABLE A WHERE not exists (select 1 from SENT_TABLE B where   A.ID = B.ID);

SPOOL OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF SPOOL OFF

(NOW USE RESULTS FROM SPOOL AND INSERT INTO THE "SENT" TABLE) 

ENDOFSQL
```

Comment: You will have to use `SLLDR` SQL Loader script to load the file into another table. It's the quickest way. Otherwise you can use `file` operations using `UTL_FILE` package and write a PLSQL block to load the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to retain a copy of `REPORT.xls` then something like below. But I would suggest you write a separate SQL Loader script for this.

```
sqlplus -S <<ENDOFSQL  || eval 'echo "Error occurred during sqlplus command line $LINENO" 1>&2; exit 1'
$USER/$PW@//$IP_PORT/$DB
    SET PAGESIZE 50000
    set feedback off
    SET MARKUP HTML ON SPOOL ON
    SET NUM 24
    SPOOL report.sql

    select 'insert into SENT values('||column1||','||column2...||');' 
    from SOMETABLE A 
    WHERE not exists (select 1 
                        from SENT_TABLE B 
                        where   A.ID = B.ID);

    SPOOL OFF;
    @report.sql 
    COMMIT;
ENDOFSQL
```

The above is as good as -

```
INSERT INTO SENT
select *
    from SOMETABLE A 
    WHERE not exists (select 1 
                        from SENT_TABLE B 
                        where   A.ID = B.ID);
```